# HTML Split SINGLE BACKGROUND IMAGE into two equal links (top and bottom)

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I am just learning HTML. Is there a way without using image mapping to split a background image into 50-50%, with each half linking to an external link? I put style=0% and 50% to split the links into the top 50% and bottom 50%, but it doesn't split the image in two.

This is what I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page 2</title>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Proxima+Nova" rel="stylesheet">

</head> 
<body>
  <div class="image">
  <center><img src="{% static 'picture.png' %}" alt="image" /></center>
    <a href="link1" style="top: 0%;"></a>
    <a href="link2" style="top: 50%;"></a>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use an image map

Comment: <center> is a deprecated tag. Use CSS to center an element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created something that does what you are looking for. It has the following limitations:

- You need to know the height of the image you are using in pixels and code the top half to be exactly half that many. When I use % instead, I wind up with the top link being bigger than the bottom. I didn't do much playing around to try and get around that.
- The image actually is loaded twice, so if your images are very big, this may be a concern for you.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.top {
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}
.bottom {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<a class="top" href="https://www.google.com"><img  src="https://placeholdit.co//i/400x400" /></a>
<a class="bottom" href="https://www.cnn.com"><img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/400x400" /></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put the `img` as a `background-image` via css, then position the links on top of a container with that background-image:

```css
.split-link-image {
  height: 400px;
  background: transparent url(http://placekitten.com/400/400) no-repeat 0 0;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

.split-link-image a {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50%;
  display: block;
}

.split-link-image a:first-child {
  top: 0;
}

.split-link-image a:last-child {
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="split-link-image">
  <a href="#top"></a>
  <a href="#bottom"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple sample:

```
<div style="position: relative; width:500px; height:500px; background-color: #667799">
    <a style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; top:0; left:0; height:50%; width:100%; box-sizing: border-box; border:solid 1px red" href="addr1"></a>
    <a style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; top:50%; left:0; height:50%; width:100%; box-sizing: border-box; border:solid 1px orange" href="addr2"></a>
</div>
```

My wrapper is `div` and i use background-color for wrapper of links ;you must use `background-image:url(imageAdress);`
Also you don't need `border` of `a` tags.